# What $T(2x^3 -x^2 - x)$ is?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B = \{p_1=x^3+1, p_2=x^3-1, p_3=x^2 + 2x, p_4=2x^2 +3\}$ a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $T:\mathbb{R}{\left[ x \right]_3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}{\left[ x \right]_3}$, such that:

$T(p_1) = 3x^2 + 5x$
$T(p_2) = 2x^3 -3x^2 -4x -2$
$T(p_3) = x^3 +4x^2 +5x +1$
$T(p_4) = 3x^3 -4x^2 -7x -3$

> Find $T(2x^3 -x^2 - x)$.

Well, because $B$ is a basis, $2x^3 -x^2 - x$ can defined as lienar combination of $B$'s terms.

Let us find the those scalars by solving the following augmented matrix:

$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2  \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & { - 1}  \\
   0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & { - 1}  \\
   1 & { - 1} & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$

The scalars vector is:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   3  \\
   { - 1}  \\
   1  \\
   { - 1}  \\
\end{array}} \right)$$

Which means that:
$$T(2{x^3} - {x^2} - x) = 3 \cdot T({p_1}) - T({p_2}) + T({p_3}) - T({p_4})$$

The problem is that calculating the above doesn't give the right answer. Why?
But more importantly, does my general proof OK?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey in the augmented matrix you need to enter the basis vectors and try to get a linear combination of them resulting in $2x^3-x^2-x$. Then, you should get the right answer.

Comment: Hhmm actually that's what I did, but somehow I wrote the wrong matrix. Let me correct this.

Comment: How do $4$ polynomials form a basis for $\mathbb R^3$? Maybe you mean $\mathbb R[x]_3$, the space of polynomials with degree less than or equal to $3$?

Comment: @ChristophPegel, you right. it's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have a mistake in the matrix. The column associated to $p_4$ should be
$$\pmatrix{0\\2\\0\\3}.$$
After fixing this you should get the correct result, your general strategy is just fine!